# Sorting questions by votes doesn't work?

Tags: bug, down-votes, sorting

I was reading **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18075200/what-does-for-int-i-0-or-whatever-it-is-mean)** "interesting" question asking what a for loop is. Needless to say it got many downvotes very fast.

Somebody in the comments said:

> Congratulations. In nine minutes, your question has become the lowest-scored visible question on SO.

I wanted to check this for myself so I sorted all SO questions by votes and went to the last page (109887 when this question was written). But the question with the lowest score was **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17492888/how-to-place-a-div-over-an-img-responsive)** question.

Is this a bug or by design? Or did I do something wrong?

**EDIT:** the last post in the sort-by-vote page is now the post that originally started this question. But Marc Gravell also found out that the question with the most downvotes is **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905734/how-to-send-100-000-emails-weekly)** question. So I guess the original question is still valid.

Comment: Caching. It's always caching.

Comment: We don't show *all* questions in every list - but: I will investigate the rules and get back to you.

Comment: So, funny story: I was wondering how [that other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17492888/how-to-place-a-div-over-an-img-responsive) had received so many downvotes (I mean, it might be *easy*, but it's well-written and answerable), but then I saw [its original version](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/17492888/1).

Comment: btw, the most downvoted question is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905734/how-to-send-100-000-emails-weekly

Comment: 148.. Wow! I wouldn't even get that many downvotes if I'd ask what you can do with that weird symbol that contains two horizontal lines.

Comment: Spammers are not looked on kindly by the Internet community. They are far less entertaining than trolls.

Comment: @Jordy 205 in extended ASCII? you can use that to build box borders in command-line apps

Comment: @MarcGravell, everbody knows that one. I mean the one people use in combination with digits and stuff.

Comment: Well, you can find it when searching per tag e.g. [this search](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java?page=9142&sort=votes&pagesize=50).

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd, it doesn't always seem work to search by tag. e.g. sorting by votes and [php] shows -12 as the lowest while the most downvoted question has -148 and is tagged with [php].

Comment: As an aside: one can search for ranges like so: [`votes:-1000..-30`](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=votes%3A-1000..-30) or simply [`votes:..-30`](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=votes%3A..-30).

Comment: @Jordy Hmm, you mean =? I think it means 2, because it has 2 bars. - means 1.

Comment: @Doorknob, I think you're right. That must mean that [≡] is 3 and [ ] is 0.

Comment: I cast the last undelete vote... I couldn't resist :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> EDIT: the last post in the sort-by-vote page is now the post that originally started this question.

Great!

> But Marc Gravell also found out that the question with the most downvotes is this question. So I guess the original question is still valid.

Nope; we explicitly exclude posts with historical locks (except on meta sites); the -148 question has a historical lock. The last 5 (at the time of writing) are: -19, -21, -24, -55, -148 : so all accounted for.

Comment: Clear as day. Thank you!